# Powershell - disable parts of Open File Dialog Box

Tags: .net, powershell

Is it possible to disable parts of the open file dialog window such as the create new folder button?

An example of the code I am using (taken from http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2009/09/01/hey-scripting-guy-september-1.aspx) is:

```
Function Get-FileName($initialDirectory)
{   
 [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") |
 Out-Null

 $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
 $OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
 $OpenFileDialog.filter = "All files (*.*)| *.*"
 $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
 $OpenFileDialog.filename
} #end function Get-FileName

Get-FileName -initialDirectory "c:\fso"
```

Thanks

Comment: My system isn't running just now so can't test, but looking at the MSDN reference, I don't think so, other than controlling the security of the call - if the user isn't privileged enough to create a folder, it may be smart enough to hide or grey out the `New Folder` button.

Comment: Since you're using a .NET class, this is really more a .NET question than a PowerShell one. You might try looking for how to do this in C# or VB.NET; if you find anything, then you'll just need to translate it.

Comment: Thanks all. I think I will look at security and permissions as a way to restrict this.

Comment: From my testing (you got me interested!) I can set an access rule to disable the current user (that the script is running under) from creating directories. But it doesn't hide the `New Folder` button - instead you get a prompt telling you `Destination Folder Access Denied`. Wasn't what you wanted but if you want the code anyway I will put up.

Comment: Thanks Graham, would like to see the code!

Comment: Done - you can hide the button system wide with a registry change, but I will have to pick up the execution of that in powershell in the morning, being past 3am here. Hopefully the ACL stuff will suffice for now :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, per the comments, this modified version of your script disables access to create folders within the target directory whilst the dialog is active then removes the block at the end before the function completes:

```
    Function Get-FileName($initialDirectory)
{   
 <#DENY CreateDirectories privilege
  to currently logged on security principal#>

 $acl = get-acl $initialDirectory

 $right = "CreateDirectories"

 $principal = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name

 $denyrule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($principal,$right,"DENY")

 $acl.AddAccessRule($denyrule)

 set-acl $initialDirectory $acl

 [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") |
 Out-Null

 $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
 $OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
 $OpenFileDialog.filter = "All files (*.*)| *.*"
 $OpenFileDialog.ReadOnlyChecked = $true
 $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
 $OpenFileDialog.filename

 #remove block now
 $acl.RemoveAccessRule($denyrule)

 set-acl $initialDirectory $acl

} #end function Get-FileName


Get-FileName -initialDirectory "c:\fso"
```

Comment: I'm glad, because the registry route is a bust. Ignoring for a moment that it's far more effort to deal with registry permissions in powershell than it should be, the key I found, when the value is deleted, hides `New Folder` button from windows explorer but not from the `OpenFileDialog`. There's a `ShowNewFolderButton` boolean value for controlling display of that button but only for the `FolderBrowserDialog` which is of no use to you here!